# Vue array content is not updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add a number to this list using a function that I have created, however, the data doesn't update. The for loop adds the data to the list, but the code above does not use it.

```js
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        row: [],
        column: [],
    }),
    methods: {
        async initGraph() {
            for(let x = 0; x < 25; x++)
            {
                this.row[x] = x;
                
            }
            for(let y = 0; y < 25; y++){
                this.column[y] = y;
            }
            console.log(this.row);
            console.log(this.column);
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.initGraph();
    } 
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="r in row" v-bind:key="r" :id="r">
                <td v-for="c in column" v-bind:key="c" :id="c" class="unvisited">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <h1>{{row}}</h1>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: You set uninitialized properties - thus they dont have vue reactivity setters. Check vue docs reactivity, or use Vue.set - or check one of those many duplicates ;)

Comment: Thank you :D, I updated it and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue cannot detect changes to the array if you modify it directly. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods
A possible solution is to use methods for the array manipulation. The following should work:

```js
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        row: [],
        column: [],
    }),
    methods: {
        initGraph() {
            for(let x = 0; x < 25; x++)
            {
                this.row.push(x);
                
            }
            for(let y = 0; y < 25; y++){
                this.column.push(y);
            }
            console.log(this.row);
            console.log(this.column);
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.initGraph();
    } 
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="r in row" v-bind:key="r" :id="r">
              <td v-for="c in column" v-bind:key="c">{{c}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :D, what would be the difference between using this method and using vue.set?

Comment: I think, Vue.set is more for replacing items... in the end, i would assume, it doesen't matter which method you use... see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays for more information about it :)

Comment: Array.push, splice ... get replaced by vue with a function using vue.set,